# Scaling constant on areas and volumes of politopes

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, area, volume

We learn in linear algebra, or even in analytical geometry that given two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ the area of the parallelogram formed by them is given by $A=||\vec{u}\times\vec{v}||$, and even more, given a third vetor $\vec{w}$ the volume of the paralelepipedal is given by $V=\langle\vec{w},\vec{u}\times\vec{v}\rangle$, we can scale the area to that of a triangle using a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ and the volume follows similar logic.

My question is, how do I find this scaling constant to find the areas and volumes of others politopes? Like a pentagon, hexagon, ...

Comment: You would have to decompose these shapes in a suitable way into triangles and parallelograms. What would $u,v$ be for a pentagon?

Comment: @LutzLehmann to be honest, I'm not really sure. In my mind there is this thought that this should be a problem of comparing the volume of the politope with it's respective parallelotope, in the case of a triangle to a parallelogram this ratio is 1:2, but in the case of other shapes I'm not sure.
Another thought that I have is that $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ can be the internal vectors that break the n-gon in to n triangles.